Can I upload my iOS app to specific groups of Internal Testers without using Xcode Cloud?
Xcode Cloud workflows allow you to specify Groups of Internal Testers to distribute your app to. For example, one workflow builds from main and is distributed to groups A and B. Another workflow builds from develop and distributes only to group A. This is easy to set up with Xcode Cloud. Unfortunately, my pre-build scripts have stopped working in the cloud, so I now run Archive locally and upload to TestFlight using the Organizer. However, I can't seem to find any way to select specific groups of Internal Testers when I do the upload. Can this be done, either through the Organizer or even from the command-line?

There is no in-built support for managing TestFlight in Xcode.  You could use the api and build your own command line tool
